# KeePass / Mono under Yosemite does not work

Tags: macos, sound-volume

I installed KeePass as described [here](http://keepass2.openix.be) but it KeePass does not start - Activity Monitor tells me that Mono is not responding. I have never used KeePass before (if this is relevant).

I am using Yosemite

I am not sure if this a Mono or a KeePass issue, but I also tried Mono 3.10 version and the same happened.

Any experiences with KeePass / Mono under Yosemite or ideas how I could troubleshoot what is happening?

I know about [KeePassX](https://www.keepassx.org) - but the consensus seems to be that KeePass is the better option?

EDIT:

I just ran keeps from the command line, and got the following output (no idea what it means...):

```
 System.EntryPointNotFoundException: GdipCreateFromContext_macosx
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdipCreateFromContext_macosx (intptr,int,int,intptr&)
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd (IntPtr hwnd) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateGraphics () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.CreateGraphicsInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase:CreateGraphicsInternal ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.Document.owner_HandleCreated (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnHandleCreated (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.OnHandleCreated (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.OnHandleCreated (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (IntPtr hWnd, Msg msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: GdipCreateFromContext_macosx
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdipCreateFromContext_macosx (intptr,int,int,intptr&)
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd (IntPtr hwnd) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateGraphics () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.CreateGraphicsInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase:CreateGraphicsInternal ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.Document.owner_HandleCreated (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnHandleCreated (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.OnHandleCreated (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.OnHandleCreated (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (IntPtr hWnd, Msg msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: GdipCreateFromContext_macosx
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdipCreateFromContext_macosx (intptr,int,int,intptr&)
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd (IntPtr hwnd) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateGraphics () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.CreateGraphicsInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.TextBoxBase_FontOrColorChanged (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnFontChanged (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.OnFontChanged (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.OnFontChanged (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Font (System.Drawing.Font value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnFontChanged (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentFontChanged (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnFontChanged (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnFontChanged (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Font (System.Drawing.Font value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.set_Font (System.Drawing.Font value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at KeePass.UI.GlobalWindowManager.CustomizeFont (System.Windows.Forms.Control c, System.Drawing.Font font) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at KeePass.UI.GlobalWindowManager.CustomizeFont (System.Windows.Forms.Control c, System.Drawing.Font font) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at KeePass.UI.GlobalWindowManager.CustomizeControl (System.Windows.Forms.Control c) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at KeePass.Forms.MainForm.OnFormLoad (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoadInternal (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at KeePass.Forms.MainForm.CleanUpEx () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at KeePass.Forms.MainForm.OnFormClosing (System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnFormClosing (System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.FireClosingEvents (CloseReason reason, Boolean cancel) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Form:FireClosingEvents (System.Windows.Forms.CloseReason,bool)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit (System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.OnThreadException (System.Exception t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoadInternal (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at KeePass.Forms.MainForm.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (IntPtr hWnd, Msg msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

Unhandled Exception:
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: GdipCreateFromContext_macosx
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdipCreateFromContext_macosx (intptr,int,int,intptr&)
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd (IntPtr hwnd) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateGraphics () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox+MessageBoxForm.InitFormsSize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox+MessageBoxForm.RunDialog () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox/MessageBoxForm:RunDialog ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show (System.String text, System.String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at KeePassLib.Utility.MessageService.SafeShowMessageBox (System.String strText, System.String strTitle, MessageBoxButtons mb, MessageBoxIcon mi, MessageBoxDefaultButton mdb) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at KeePassLib.Utility.MessageService.ShowFatal (System.Object[] vLines) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at KeePass.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: GdipCreateFromContext_macosx
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdipCreateFromContext_macosx (intptr,int,int,intptr&)
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd (IntPtr hwnd) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateGraphics () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox+MessageBoxForm.InitFormsSize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox+MessageBoxForm.RunDialog () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox/MessageBoxForm:RunDialog ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show (System.String text, System.String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at KeePassLib.Utility.MessageService.SafeShowMessageBox (System.String strText, System.String strTitle, MessageBoxButtons mb, MessageBoxIcon mi, MessageBoxDefaultButton mdb) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at KeePassLib.Utility.MessageService.ShowFatal (System.Object[] vLines) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at KeePass.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be solved by installing a new version of mono which fixes this issue, as explained [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27011/fix-for-gdipcreatefromcontext-macosx-and-other-macios-gdi-issues?new=1):

> Try installing this mono 3.10 version and forcing a rebuild of your
>   application.
>
> https://www.dropbox.com/s/wrjnv7p8zj1rh5u/MonoFramework-MDK-3.10.0.26.macos10.xamarin.x86.pkg?dl=0
>
> One of the developers on the mono team worked hard to track down and
>   fix this issue. Hopefully, this should be the end of the GDI issues
>   for Xamarin.Mac users.
>
> Thanks, -- Chris H

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Neither the 3.10 nor the 3.8 versions of Mono would work for me. The **2**.10, however, did! You can download it here: http://download.mono-project.com/archive/2.10.12/macos-10-x86/

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this problem and tried the current version of mono, 4.0.5.1, but it didn't work, so I ran the [uninstall script](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/osx/).

mono 3.10.0.26 sounded promising but I wanted to download from the developers. Closest version found was [3.10.0.31](http://download.mono-project.com/archive/3.10.0/macos-10-x86/MonoFramework-MDK-3.10.0.31.macos10.xamarin.x86.pkg), which worked!